# Is there are another easier way to writer that program?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have created a program, in which the user have to enter a sequence and the program have to  compare each three letters with a data entered before in the program. And the total data are 25 cases, which mean that the program have to compare each 3 char of the Userseq by a total of 25 cases (25 if statement for each 3 char). Then after completing the first 3 char, it move to the next 3 char till the userseq finish. And if the first 3 char for exemple equals one of the data entered before, it have to display it on the output. I want another way with less code and which abreviate my all if statement. And I have another problem, that I asked the program for exemple to do the same thing, the same comparision till the tenth group of 3 char of the userseq. And in case the user have entered less than ten group of 3 char (which mean less than 30 char), the programe say "Unhandled exception: System.ArgumentOutofrangeException: Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Here's my code. NB, those code I wrote them 10 times by changing only the userseq number (userseq1, userseq2..). Is there is a way to write to the programe to repeat the same work for each group of 3 char till the userseq end ?

```
Console.Write("Enter your sequecnce: ");
        string Userseq = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] aa1 = { "TTT", "TTC" };
        string[] aa2 = { "TTA", "TTG" };
        string[] aa3 = { "CTT", "CTC", "CTA", "CTG" };
        string[] aa4 = { "ATT", "ATC", "ATA" };
        string[] aa5 = { "ATG" };
        string[] aa6 = { "GTT", "GTC", "GTA", "GTG" };
        string[] aa7 = { "TCT", "TCC", "TTCA", "TCG" };
        string[] aa8 = { "CCT", "CCC", "CCA", "CCG" };
        string[] aa9 = { "ACT", "ACC", "ACA", "ACG" };
        string[] aa10 = { "GCT", "GCC", "GCA", "GCG" };
        string[] aa11 = { "TAT", "TAC" };
        string[] aa12 = { "TAA", "TAG" };
        string[] aa13 = { "CAT", "CAC" };
        string[] aa14 = { "CAA", "CAG" };
        string[] aa15 = { "AAT", "AAC" };
        string[] aa16 = { "AAA", "AAG" };
        string[] aa17 = { "GAT", "GAC" };
        string[] aa18 = { "GAA", "GAG" };
        string[] aa19 = { "TGT", "TGC" };
        string[] aa20 = { "TGA" };
        string[] aa21 = { "TGG" };
        string[] aa22 = { "CGT", "CGC", "CGA", "CGG" };
        string[] aa23 = { "AGT", "AGC" };
        string[] aa24 = { "AGA", "AGG" };
        string[] aa25 = { "GGT", "GGC", "GGA", "GGG" };
        string Userseq1 = Userseq.Substring(0, 3);
        if (aa1.Contains(Userseq1))
        {
            Console.Write("Phe" + " ");
        }
        else if (aa2.Contains(Userseq1))
        {
            Console.Write("Leu" + " ");
        }
        else if (aa3.Contains(Userseq1))
        {
            Console.Write("Leu" + " ");
        }
        else if (aa4.Contains(Userseq1))
        {
            Console.Write("Ile" + " ");
        }
        else if (aa5.Contains(Userseq1))
        {
            Console.Write("Met" + " ");
        }
        else if (aa6.Contains(Userseq1))
        {
            Console.Write("Val" + " ");
        }
        else if (aa7.Contains(Userseq1))
        {
            Console.Write("Ser" + " ");
        }
        else if (aa8.Contains(Userseq1))
        {
            Console.Write("Pro" + " ");
        }
        else if (aa9.Contains(Userseq1))
        {
            Console.Write("Thr" + " ");
        }
        else if (aa10.Contains(Userseq1))
        {
            Console.Write("Ala" + " ");
        }
        else if (aa11.Contains(Userseq1))
        {
            Console.Write("Tyr" + " ");
        }
        else if (aa12.Contains(Userseq1))
        {
            Console.Write("STOP" + " ");
        }
        else if (aa13.Contains(Userseq1))
        {
            Console.Write("His" + " ");
        }
        else if (aa14.Contains(Userseq1))
        {
            Console.Write("Gin" + " ");
        }
        else if (aa15.Contains(Userseq1))
        {
            Console.Write("Asn" + " ");
        }
        else if (aa16.Contains(Userseq1))
        {
            Console.Write("Lys" + " ");
        }
        else if (aa17.Contains(Userseq1))
        {
            Console.Write("Asp" + " ");
        }
        else if (aa18.Contains(Userseq1))
        {
            Console.Write("Glu" + " ");
        }
        else if (aa19.Contains(Userseq1))
        {
            Console.Write("Cys" + " ");
        }
        else if (aa20.Contains(Userseq1))
        {
            Console.Write("STOP" + " ");
        }
        else if (aa21.Contains(Userseq1))
        {
            Console.Write("Trp" + " ");
        }
        else if (aa22.Contains(Userseq1))
        {
            Console.Write("Arg" + " ");
        }
        else if (aa23.Contains(Userseq1))
        {
            Console.Write("Ser" + " ");
        }
        else if (aa24.Contains(Userseq1))
        {
            Console.Write("Arg" + " ");
        }
        else if (aa25.Contains(Userseq1))
        {
            Console.Write("Gly" + " ");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" \n You entered an invalid character. Other than A, T, C and G. Please check and retry.");
        }
```

Comment: You *can* create jagged arrays, ie arrays containing arrays. Or create an array of objects that have a Name and Sequence properties

Comment: I think i would do it with a dictionary. The key would be the 3 digits of the sequence, and the value the text you want to show ("Phe","Leu"...)

Comment: Yes, it can be much more compact. 1) Define 2-dimensional array - instead of `aa1`, `aa2` use one array. 2) Add console output strings after check values and all checking will go in simple loop. Compare `N-1` strings and the final one is for `Console.Write` output.

Comment: Downvoters, please consider that a) you didn't know these are *enzymes* b) there can be a *lot* of them, as in several thousands and c) bioinformatics students aren't programmers by training, they are biologists.

Answer (score 6):

Create a class with a Name and Sequence property to hold each sequence, eg :

```
class EnzymeSequence
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string[] Enzymes {get;set;}

    public EnzymeSequence(string name,string[] enzymes)
    {
        Name=name;
        Enzymes=enzymes;
    }
}
```

and create an array or list of sequences where you add all the sequences you want:

```
var sequences=new EnzymeSequence[]{
                  new EnzymeSequence("Phe",new[]{{ "TTT", "TTC" }),
                  ...
              };
```

To find a sequence you can write:

```
var match=sequences.FirstOrDefault(ez=>ez.Enzymes.Contains(Userseq1));
```

The result will be the sequence that contains what the user entered or null.

```
if (match==null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(" \n You entered an invalid character. Other than A, T, C and G. Please check and retry.");
}
else
{
    Console.Write("{0} ",match.Name);
}
```

If you want to find all sequences that have a certain enzyme:

```
var matches=sequences.Where(ez=>ez.Enzymes.Contains(Userseq1));
```

If you only want the matching names:

```
var names=sequences.Where(ez=>ez.Enzymes.Contains(Userseq1))
                  .Select(ez=>ez.Name);
var line=String.Join(" ",names);
Concole.WriteLine(line);
```

If you have a *lot* of sequences you could use Parallel LINQ to perform the lookup in parallel:

```
var names=sequences.AsParallel()
                   .Where(ez=>ez.Enzymes.Contains(Userseq1))
                  .Select(ez=>ez.Name);

var line=String.Join(" ",names);
Concole.WriteLine(line);
```

PLINQ will only show an improvement if there are a *lot* of sequences involved, in the order of several thousands.

Another option is to create a "reverse" dictionary that matches enzymes to sequences. Since many sequences can contain the same enzyme, we need to group the sequence-enzyme pairs by their enzyme before creating a dictionary keyed by enzyme:

```
var enzymeSequences=(from seq in sequences
                        from enzyme in seq.Enzymes
                        let pair = new { seq.Name, enzyme }
                        group pair by enzyme into enzymeSeqs
                        select enzymeSeqs);
var enzymeDict= enzymeSequences.ToDictionary(
                        grp => grp.Key, 
                        grp=> grp.Select(pair=>pair.Name)
                                    .ToArray());

var matches = enzymeDict["AGG"];
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", matches));
```

Comment: Better than my dictionary suggestion. +1

Comment: Thank you for this answer. By the way, those aren't enzymes, they are amino acides.

Comment: @WassimDernayka I'm not a biologist, I'm married to one. I just googled a sequence and picked the first thing that looked like a noun from the *result* page. I've heard both words before, so ...

Answer (score 0):

I would take the approach of using a Dictionary, as follows:

```
public class TestClass
{
    private Dictionary<string, List<string>> sequences;

    public TestClass()
    {
        sequences = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
        sequences.Add("Phe", new List<string>() {"TTT", "TTC"});
        // Repeat for all the sequences.
    }

    public string GetSequenceType(string sequence)
    {
        foreach (var key in sequences.Keys)
        {
            if (sequences[key].Contains(sequence)
                return key;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't gain anything by using a Dictionary since you don't search the key. You do pay a penalty though because hashes and buckets have to be calculated for each entry. The key in this case is the *sequences*, not the name. A (multi)dictionary would be helpful though if each sequence enzyme was added as the key and the sequence name as the value - a reverse dictionary if you will